# Does java have an equivalent to python __call__?

Tags: java, python

Just started learning python, I've come across `__call__` method. I understand when `__init__` gets called and when `__call__` gets called by running a simple example:

```
class Constructor:
    def __init__(self, a):
        print "__init__ called"

    def __call__(self):
        print "__call__ called"

    def dummy(self):
        print "a dummy method called"

print "creating x obj"
x = Constructor(1)
print "calling x object"
x()
```

console output:

```
creating x obj
__init__ called
calling x object
__call__ called
```

My questions are:

1. I come from java background, I know `__init__` maps to java constructor, does java have an equivalent to `__call__` to help me understand this better?
2. Can someone give me a simple example of when `__call__` can be useful?

Comment: I think what you might use is the Runnable interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html it is very simple, just a run() method. Build an object that implements the runnable interface and then call x.run(). Interfaces (like this, or your own) make the Observer pattern possible, which IMO is the single most important pattern for writing reusable objects. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: This is where I get confused, if you can simple do x.run() by defining a simple method called run() in the python class. Why python bothers at all to design something like __ call __?

Comment: In python `__call__` is a base of the language (see http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work/) and helpfull to solving several problems/tasks like observer pattern, callback and so on.

Comment: It is also a way to replace a function with a configurable class object at a later time, without changing the code where the function was called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__call__` equates to overloading the `()` operator on a class. This is possible in C++ but not Java. It allows one to have *function objects* (sometimes called *functors*).

In Python these are termed *callable objects*.

In simple terms, this allows you to treat an object as a function.

The actual use for such concepts is beyond the scope of this answer but there is plenty of information around the internet. For example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).

Comment: In Python they're called *callable objects*, not functors.  Functor already means something else in computer science anyway.

Comment: I think `Functor` and `Function Object` and `Callable Object` all mean the same thing - there may of course be other meanings of each.

Comment: Well, the main meaning of "functor" (from category theory) is very important.  But I think the term "functor" for callable object is only really used within the C++ community.  You won't find the term "functor" in the Python documentation *anywhere*, but "callable" is common.

Comment: @Nick I get the point now, can you give an example where callable object might be useful. How it's different from a simple method?

Comment: @Shengjie: It isn't different, except for the syntax.

Comment: @DietrichEpp point taken. You can probably guess I'm from a C/C++ background!

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is nothing like `__call__` in Java. You cannot use an object as a method call. You have to create a method and call it:

```
class Constructor{
    Constructor(){
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }

    void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("do called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Creatng x obj");
        x = new Constuctor();
        System.out.println("Calling x obj");
        x.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: so in your example, doStuff pretty much plays the role of '__call__' here.